# Finding dom index based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML markup is like this

```
<div> 
    <div class="selector"></div> 
 </div>
 <div>
    <div class="selector"></div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <div class="selector1"></div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <div class="selector1 active"></div>
 </div>
<div>
    <div class="selector2"></div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <div class="selector2"></div>
 </div>
```

Based on user click, I want to find clicked bucket and based on that bucket I want to find its index.

Javascript

```
var sectionType = $(this).attr('class');
var sectionIndex = sectionType.find("active").index();
```

But Its not giving me the selected/hover element index. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What do you mean by index? Is this the position of the element according to the Dom?

Comment: What should be the result in your case? 0 or 1?

Comment: In my case the result should be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a DOM element to the `index` method, then it returns the index of that element in jQuery collection.

```
$('div[class]').click(function () {
    var cls = this.className.split(' ')[0];
    var index = $('div.' + cls).index(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kCPYM/

Index of `.active` element:

```
$('div[class]').click(function () {
    var cls = this.className.split(' ')[0],
        $div = $('div.' + cls),
        $active = $div.filter('.active'),
        index = $div.index($active);

    console.log(cls, index);
});
```

Comment: I can't say this.className.split(' ')[0]; Because say if the markup is something like this <div>
    <div class="product">selector</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="product">selector</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="product">selector1</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="item active">selector1</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="item">selector2</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="rough">selector2</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="rough">selector2</div>
</div>
It will not work.

Comment: @saorabh Why do you think so? Can you provide a demo where it doesn't work?

Comment: `Index` of the third `.product` element should be `0`? Why? It works for me, note that alert only accepts one parameter, what exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.someclass').click(function(){
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

Comment: But it will return index based on DOM

Comment: you can give them some class